# list<type> access in webform markup

Tags: asp.net

my datasource is a list of customers in a webforms project

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
    customers.Add(new Customer() { FirstName = "John", PhoneNumber = "999.999.9999" });
    customers.Add(new Customer() { FirstName = "Jane", PhoneNumber = "999.999.9999" });

}
```

is there a way to iterate that in an aspx page of a web forms project. (this is easy in mvc using the model)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) control for this. Here is an example:

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="CustomerRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span>Name:</span> <%# Eval("FirstName") %>
        <span>Phone:</span> <%# Eval("PhoneNumber ") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
    customers.Add(new Customer() { FirstName = "John", PhoneNumber = "999.999.9999" });
    customers.Add(new Customer() { FirstName = "Jane", PhoneNumber = "999.999.9999" });

    CustomerRepeater.DataSource = customers;
    CustomerRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataSource' of server control: (in example DropDownList)

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.ddlCustomers.DataSource = this.GetCustomers();
        this.ddlCustomers.DataBind();
    }
}

public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
    customers.Add(new Customer() { FirstName = "John", PhoneNumber = "999.999.9999" });
    customers.Add(new Customer() { FirstName = "Jane", PhoneNumber = "999.999.9999" });

    return customers;
}
```

Default.aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCustomers" runat="server" DataTextField="FirstName" DataValueField="FirstName"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Or if you needed you can use 'MVC-style' in aspx:

```
<% foreach(WebApplication1.Customer customer in this.GetCustomers()) { %>
    <span><%= customer.FirstName %></span>
<% } %>
```